# TapTargetView is placed behind popup menu

Tags: android, popup, target, tap

I created TapTargetView (or TapTargetSequence) in all of my activities and it displaying well, but for inner views of popup menu, it hides behind my popup menu window! exactly between under activity and popup menu. how can I bring it to top, please? Is parameter of TapTargetSequence ((Activity) context) correct? "context" or "this" occurs error !

```
public class Popup_Menu implements OnClickListener {

PopupWindow popup;      View layout;        Context context;
WindowManager wm;

    void showPopup(final Activity context) {
        this.context=context;
                        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout_menu, viewGroup);

                        // Creating the PopupWindow
       popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
                        // Clear the default translucent background
       popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 30 ,0 );

    tapTarget_menu();

    }       /////////////////// close of showPopup() !








    // TapTaget_menu
public void tapTarget_menu() {
    new TapTargetSequence((Activity) context)
            .targets(
                    TapTarget.forView(layout.findViewById(R.id.chkb_menu_remem), "remember", "last lesson")
// first target
                            .targetCircleColor(R.color.sabz_seyedi)
                            .outerCircleColor(R.color.sabzabi_kmrng)
                            .dimColor(R.color.sabz_seyedi)
                            .titleTextSize(22)
                            .descriptionTextSize(16)
                            .textColor(R.color.white)
                            .drawShadow(true)
                            .transparentTarget(true)
                            .cancelable(false)
                            .targetRadius(60),
// second target
                    TapTarget.forView(layout.findViewById(R.id.ll_call_menu), "call", "connecting friends!")
                            .targetCircleColor(R.color.sabz_seyedi)
                            .outerCircleColor(R.color.sabzabi_tireh)
                            .dimColor(R.color.sabz_seyedi)
                            .titleTextSize(22)
                            .descriptionTextSize(16)
                            .textColor(R.color.white)
                            .drawShadow(true)
                            .transparentTarget(true)
                            .cancelable(false)
                            .targetRadius(60)
            ).start();
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I found my solution ! I have changed this code after popup.showAtLocation(), like following and it can display tapTargetView on top of PopupWindow.
VIVA ME !!!

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.packageName = context.getPackageName();
    layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;
```

then, out of showPopup() method:

```
public void tapTarget_menu1(){
    TapTarget target = TapTarget.forView(layout.findViewById(R.id.ll_call_menu), "remember", "last lesson");
                                .targetCircleColor(R.color.sabz_seyedi)
                                .outerCircleColor(R.color.sabzabi_tireh)
                                .titleTextSize(24)
                                .descriptionTextSize(18)
                                .textColor(R.color.black)
                                .drawShadow(true)
                                .cancelable(false)
                                .transparentTarget(true)
                                .targetRadius(60);

    content = (ViewGroup) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final TapTargetView tapTarget_menu1 = new TapTargetView(context, wm, content, target, new TapTargetView.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
            tapTarget_menu2();
            super.onTargetClick(view);
        }
    });
    ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(tapTarget_menu1, layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Does not work, app crashed... do you have other solution?